# Scala tuples to hierarchy

Tags: scala, tuples, slick

In Slick, SQL joins like this:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.name, c.name, c.added from A a join B b join C c
```

will return tuples like these:

```
(1,Jim,Some(Foo),Mark,Some(2018-06-14T08:06:56Z))
(1,Jim,Some(Foo),Anne,Some(2018-06-14T12:04:50Z))
(1,Jim,Some(Bar),Jose,Some(2018-06-14T17:40:19Z))
```

What is the most Scala-way of transforming such tuples into a hierarchy? E.g.:

```
Map(
    "id" -> 1,
    "name" -> "Jim",
    "projects" -> List(
        Map(
            "name" -> "Foo",
            "staffs" -> List(
                Map(
                    "name" -> "Mark",
                    "added" -> "2018-06-14T08:06:56Z"
                ),
                Map(
                    "name" -> "Anne",
                    "added" -> "2018-06-14T12:04:50Z"
                )
            )
        ),
        Map(
            "name" -> "Bar",
            "staffs" -> List(
                Map(
                    "name" -> "Jose",
                    "added" -> "2018-06-14T17:40:19Z"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Note that the resulting object will be converted to JSON using Jackson.

Comment: The structure (1,Jim,Some(Foo),Mark,Some(2018-06-14T08:06:56Z)) will be of constant size or this will be variable. If it's of constant size, then it's more easy.

Comment: Can you also post an example input tuple data structure in which u get the data from SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `groupBy()` operator to collect tuples with common fields. The first `groupBy` below selects on the first two fields and maps them to `Map` entries for the `id` and the `name`. The second, nested `groupBy` does a sub-selection on the project field and creates a list of projects. The third iteration now picks up the staff associated with the project.

```
val listOfProjectMaps = resultList.groupBy(t => (t._1, t._2))
 .map({
  case (k, v) => Map(
    "id" -> k._1,
    "name" -> k._2,
    "projects" ->
      v.groupBy(tv => tv._3.get)
      .map({
        case (k1, v1) =>
          Map(
            "name" -> k1,
            "staffs" ->
              v1.map(v2 => Map(
                "name" -> v2._4,
                "added" -> v2._5.get)))
      }))
})
```

Note this approach, while straightforward does not handle bad data at all well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it;
Start by creating classes for your project domain.

```
case class Manager(managerId: Int, name: String)

case class Project(projectId: Int, name: String, staffIds: List[Int])

case class Staff(staffId: Int, name: String, added: String) // or java.time.ZonedDateTime
```

Then set up your Slick database mappings like this example [gist](https://gist.github.com/retrospectacus/2c2f232337c7b68f42dee3ea92762633). You could use `split(",")` and `toInt` and `mkString(",")` to persist the `List[Int]` in `Project`, or use a join table and `case class StaffOnProject(projectId: Int, staffId: Int)`.
Now you can gather your data using joins in your service class something like this; I would say there are a lot of ways to do this part.

```
// Probably not what I would do but this is the structure you asked for
case class ProjectWithStaff(project: Project, staff: List[Staff])
case class ManagerWithProjectsAndStaff(manager: Manager, projects: List[ProjectWithStaff])

def getManagerWithProjectsAndStaff(managerId:Int): Future[ManagerWithProjectsAndStaff] =
  for {
    manager <- db.run(Managers.byId(managerId).result.head)
    projects <- db.run(Projects.byManager(managerId).result)
    staffs <- db.run(Staffs.table.filter(_.staffId inSet projects.flatMap(_.staffIds).toSet).result)
  } yield ManagerWithProjectsAndStaff(
    manager,
    projects.map(p => {
      val projectStaff = staffs.filter(s => p.staffIds.contains(s.staffId))
      ProjectWithStaff(p, projectStaff)
    })
  )
```

All of these case classes can be (de)serialized by Jackson. The `ManagerWithProjectsAndStaff` will be serialized in the format you described.